# Can i disable AWS Cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-java-sdk

Does AWS Cognito have an option to disable user pool ?

When i look at the AWS Console i don't see anything like this, despite this I have found this in the documentation as a property of user pool.

**UserPoolDescriptionType:**

```
Status

    The user pool status in a user pool description.

    Type: String

    Valid Values: Enabled | Disabled

    Required: No
```

Documentation:

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UserPoolDescriptionType.html

Java SDK:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/userpooldescriptiontype.html#status

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the user pool, or you can delete all of the clients for the user pool, but there is no option to disable it. You can find all of the [actions that are available here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but may be you can update the user pool to only have Administrator created users. https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-admin-create-user-policy.html